# Auto Scrolling of horizontal list items with timer in android

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview, autoscroll

I need to show advertisements in my app with datas fetched from web services. I have displayed the ads in horizontal listview. Now I want each cell of the listview to be scrolled automatically at particular time interval (as like google ads). How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way, I think, is to use a handler in your activity, or fragment. Just add the code like this:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(runnable, interval);
```

and in your runnable you should implement scrolling of your listview.

**UPDATE** If you will use ViewPager instead of scrollview you can make it this way:

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    Runnable runable = new Runnable() { 

        @Override 
        public void run() {
            //this will select next page number
            page = page==maxPages? 0 : ++page;
            //this will change the page to concrete page number
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(page);
            //this will execute this code after timeInterval
            handler.postDelayed(this, timeInterval);
        } 
    }; 
    handler.postDelayed(runable, timeInterval);
```

where `viewPager` is your ViewPager instance, `timeInterval` - time interval in milliseconds after which you want to scroll the page, `maxPages` - number of last page that you have in your ViewPager

Comment: I dont want the ad to run horizontally. Instead it should move cell by cell(like image swiping in gallery) automatically

Comment: so, may be it is better for you to use ViewPager instead of horizontal scrollview? It can move your items cell by cell

Comment: If i use viewpager is it possible to move the cell automatically?

Comment: Yes, but you still need a handler to do it with time interval. I've updated my answer to make it more clear